# Make custom Gradle task, that generates code, run on IDE import

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, code-generation, gradle-kotlin-dsl

Since there is no Gradle plugin for axis2 (a wsdl code generator), I called an Ant task in a custom Gradle task.

As of now `./gradlew build` generates the code, and `./gradlew clean` deletes it. Also, the code is only generated if changes in the input file(s) or in the output directory are detected.

The only problem I'm having is that the code is not generated automatically when the project is imported into an IDE.

How do I need to change the `build.gradle.kts` below in order to have the IDEs (currently IntelliJ, but I would also like support for Eclipse) generate the code on import?

---

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("base") // needed for delete
}

val axis2 by configurations.creating

dependencies {
    axis2("org.apache.axis2:axis2-ant-plugin:$axis2Version")
    axis2("org.apache.axis2:axis2-xmlbeans:$axis2Version")
}


val wsdl2Java by tasks.registering {
    group = "build"
    description = "Creates Java classes and resources from WSDL schema."

    inputs.files(fileTree("$projectDir/src/main/resources/wsdl"))
    outputs.dir("$projectDir/generated/")

    doLast {
        ant.withGroovyBuilder {
            "echo"("message" to "Generating Classes from WSDL!")
            "taskdef"("name" to "codegen", "classname" to "org.apache.axis2.tool.ant.AntCodegenTask", "classpath" to axis2.asPath)
            "codegen"(
                    "wsdlfilename" to "$projectDir/src/main/resources/wsdl/MP12N-H-HOST-WEB-SOAP.wsdl",
                    "output" to "$projectDir/generated/",
                    "targetSourceFolderLocation" to "src/main/java",
                    "targetResourcesFolderLocation" to "src/main/resources",
                    "packageName" to "de.hanel.com.jws.main",
                    "databindingName" to "xmlbeans")
        }
    }
}


val deleteGenerated by tasks.registering(Delete::class) {
    delete("$projectDir/generated/")
}

tasks {
    compileJava {
        dependsOn(wsdl2Java)
    }

    clean {
        dependsOn(deleteGenerated)
    }
}

java {
    sourceSets["main"].java {
        srcDir("generated/src/main/java")
    }

    sourceSets["main"].resources {
        srcDir("generated/src/main/resources")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a working solution now. Both Eclipse and IntelliJ generate the source code on import.

First we add the IDE-specific plugins.

```
apply {
    plugin("idea")
    plugin("eclipse")
}
```

Then we get the corresponding IDE tasks and add our own task, that was defined in `val wsdl2Java`, as dependency

```
// find by name (in tasks container), since a module is also called 'idea'
project.tasks.findByName("idea")?.dependsOn(wsdl2Java)
project.tasks.findByName("eclipse")?.dependsOn(wsdl2Java)
```

---

The only problem is that apparently Eclipse can't handle

```
java {
    sourceSets["main"].java {
        srcDir("generated/src/main/java")
    }

    sourceSets["main"].resources {
        srcDir("generated/src/main/resources")
    }
}
```

But that's a different question.

**UPDATE**

The code block below tells Eclipse to include the generated sources

```
eclipse {
    classpath {
        plusConfigurations.add(configurations.findByName("compile"))
    }
}
```

and this tells IntelliJ to mark the generated, and already included, sources as generated

```
idea {
    module {
        generatedSourceDirs.add(file("generated/src/main/java"))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [mark any task or run configuration to be activated](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gradle.html#config_triggers_gradle) before/after Gradle import or IDE make:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but that's not exactly what I asked :-) I want to configure the build system. **It** should tell the IDE what to do. This way it's easier for other users (and for me if I combe back to the project some later time).

Comment: Looks like the https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-160605 is what you need then. I'll update the answer.